# Automatically spacing sequences of relations and binary operators

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In some cases it is common to use the same symbol to refer to a mathematical relation and to instances of the relation. For example, `>` as the relation of being greater than and `x>y` for the instance saying that `x` is greater than `y`.

You can manipulate relations for example

```
>' = > \cup \{(x,y)\}
```

Normally, TeX automatically adds (the right) amount of space around math relations and binary operators. However, the spacing must be adjusted manually in scenarios like the example above, for example:

```
{>'} = {>} \cup \{(x,y)\}
\mathord{>}' = \mathord{>} \cup \{(x,y)\}
```

I wonder if there are ways to handle situations like the one above automatically (beside the solutions above or defining commands for the relations, e.g., `\newcommand{\greater}{\mathord{>}}`, and then

```
\greater' = \greater \cup \{(x,y)\}
```

Comment: The only way would be to make the leading character active so as to gauge the following input and construct a symbol accordingly. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think to `$<\subset\le$`, where the fact that `\le` is not to be considered a relation symbol depends on what comes before. So you'd need to define a parser for your expressions, which is not something I would do.

I suggest you to *prefix* a relation symbol when it's to be considered an ordinary one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\begingroup\lccode`~=``
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1{\mathord{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode``=\string"8000 }


\begin{document}
$`>' = `> \cup \{(x,y)\}$

${>'} = {>} \cup \{(x,y)\}$ % for checking the result
\end{document}
```

The character `` ` `` is free of meaning in formulas (and it's handy to produce on my keyboard); you can also use `?`.

[image]

Alternatively, you can decide to *quote* the symbol; again, I'm used to it because of this site:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\begingroup\lccode`~=``
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1`{\mathord{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode``=\string"8000 }


\begin{document}
$`>'` = `>` \cup \{(x,y)\}$

${>'} = {>} \cup \{(x,y)\}$ % for checking the result
\end{document}
```

What's in between back quotes is considered an ordinary symbol. This might be more *semantically sound*, take your pick.

Comment: Not exactly what I was after, still need to manually signal that a symbol has to be treated differently from its "normal" beahviour. The  second one is a nice technical solution, but I would prefer to use {} instead of `.

Comment: As I said, parsing those expressions is not very easy; at least that's my feeling. Without a proper parsing rule, it's very difficult to provide a solution that doesn't rely on additional markup. And writing a proper parser, even if the rules are clearly laid out, might reveal quite difficult.